# TCP Connection refused in Streaming Context of apache Spark, python

Tags: sockets, server, pyspark, spark-streaming

I wish to receive data from an android application "IMU+GPS sensorstream" link : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lorenz_fenster.sensorstreamgps&hl=en

I need to make a spark Dstream out of it. But I receive below error.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext


spc = SparkContext(appName="testReceive")
stc = StreamingContext(spc, 5)

#Is there an error in below line? 
lines = stc.socketTextStream("localhost" , 5555)

words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

wordCounts.pprint()

stc.start()

stc.awaitTermination()

ERROR :

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-12-06 10:48:55
-------------------------------------------

16/12/06 10:48:55 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Error connecting to localhost:5555
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**I have forwarded port '5555' which is in use.**

If I use below program to receive the data it is **successful**. 
Hence in a similar way how can I receive data to make it a spark stream.

Please help, stuck with it for more than a week now!!.

```
import socket, traceback

host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

while True:
    try:
        message, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
        message = message.decode() 
        data = message.split(",")
        print(data)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 0):

lines = stc.socketTextStream("localhost" , 5555) there is no error in it.

U can use NetCat to send data through the port 5555.
Downoad netcat and unzip to a folder .
From the command line navigate to the path where u unzipped net and run the following code:
nc -l -p  (5555 in your case) on windows
This opens the port 5555 to listen.
Now run your pySpark code.
Start to input code in the command line and you can see them count in the Python console.

Answer (score 0):

Check NetCat service is started or not before executing job on port: `5555`

To check NetCat is installed or not -
Run command on cmd:

```
nc
```

If you see this,

```
Cmd line:
```

then `NetCat` is already installed.
Start service on specified port.

If not, then
1. download NetCat from internet (search for netcat for windows - zip)
2. extract in `C:\ drive`
3. Set windows Environment variable: go to Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Edit Path and and add new path like C:\netcat -> Ok -> Ok
4. Re-open cmd and check command `nc`

Start NetCat Service on specified port (on cmd terminal):

```
nc -l -p 5555
```

Now run (using spark-submit or through any editor like pycharm) stream job. and keep giving input's from cmd terminal for results.